# Users not logged can see my application in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have a problem where, if I not logged into my facebook account I can see (even so) my application, writing the url of it. In other words, "anonymous users" on facebook can see my aplication.

What I know is, how do I prevent users no logged can't see my application and are redirected to login to facebook?

Can I do with a configuration of my own facebook application? or should I program it with the SDK or JS Facebook?
Can anyone recommend a page or an example for how to do?

NOTE: I use PHP with CodeIgniter for my app.

Comment: when you say they can "see" you app, do you mean the content it's displaying and that this should only be for people who have authorised it?

Comment: @TommyBs No.. My application displaying the content for all users, logged and NO logged in their facebook accounts. Only typing the URL of my application can see it. My goal is to prevent users not logged in, can view the application. The most desirable is to be redirected to the facebook login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you aren't using the SDK properly to check if a user is logged in. You then basically need to wrap your content in an if-else statement. I dont know if there is a plugin for codeigniter you're using but in the php-sdk, in it's simplest terms it's like this:

```
  include "facebook.php";
  $facebook = new Facebook(array("appId"=>YOUR_APP_ID, "secret"=>YOUR_SECRET));
  $me = $facebook->getUser();
  $user = false;
  if($me){ // still try and get user as getUser could return valid result
     try{
     $user = $facebook->api('/me');
     catch(facebookAPIException $e){
     $user = false;
     $me = false;
     }
 }


if($user){ // display your content here

}else{// user not logged in
   header("Location:".$facebook->getLoginUrl());
}
```

The above example is in its most simple form but info about the php sdk is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ and you can download it to look at the examples. As I say this is just plain php, not integrated in codeigniter and is very much just psuedo code. If you pasted some of  your code it might help to solve this, especially for someone else more experienced in codeigniter. But to me it sounds like you aren't checking if the user exists and either forwarding or wrapping your content in a statement that stops them viewing it. I'm not sure how this works on a canvas app but I know this works for website authentication. If this is a canvas app you're talking about, you could try checking the "authenticated referrals" checkbox for your app, or use the JS sdk to redirect them if the user isn't recognised, similar to the above

Answer (score 0):

If other users can't see the app, You've almost certainly forgotten to take the app out of sandbox mode or have restricted it demographically - change that in the app settings

{edit: you've edited your question to be almost the opposite of what it was before

the PHP sample app includes code to check if the current user uses your app and you can do different operations (including a redirect to the auth dialog) in this case